# How to write jquery's parent().parent().parent() in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i re-write this jquery code into pure javascript code.

```
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
```

I did this:

```
this.parentNode.removeChild(this); // not working.
```

My html code is inside my javascript

```
div.innerHTML =
'<img src="img.png">
<div class="first">
   <div class="second">
      <a href="#">click me to remove img </a>
   </div>
</div>'
```

Comment: You missed 2 `parentNode` calls, and `this` needs to be an htmlelement and it won't be the child since an element can't be in two places at once. Basically what you have will never work

Comment: Well other than that I personally would never write that atrocious line of jQuery to begin with. The answer is ^ what he said.

Comment: `this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.remove()`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to remove the current element. You can do that with the [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) method

```js
document.getElementById('world').parentNode.parentNode.remove()
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span id="hello">Hello</span>
    <span id="world">World</span>
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>
    <span id="brass">Brass</span>
    <span id="monkey">Monkey</span>
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>
    <span id="im">I'm</span>
    <span id="batman">Batman</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Another thing you can do instead of using `parentNode` one thousand times, is to use [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```js
document.getElementById('world').closest('.group').remove()
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <p>
    <span id="hello">Hello</span>
    <span id="world">World</span>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <p>
    <span id="brass">Brass</span>
    <span id="monkey">Monkey</span>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <p>
    <span id="im">I'm</span>
    <span id="batman">Batman</span>
  </p>
</div>
```